# Is there any way to get the real-time x-axis values of a vertical line being dragged in react-plotly.js?

Tags: reactjs, graph, plotly.js

I have a graph with time (JS date) on x-axis. I want to add a vertical line to it which can be dragged and also get the real-time x-axis values while the said line is being dragged. Is it possible in react-plotly.js to get real-time values?

So far, I made the config {editable:true} to be able to drag the line and I'm using onRelayout={handleRelayout} to get the final value from the event object when the I stop dragging the line.